# AttributeError when creating new user using serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I'm making registration of new user. This is it's model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .validators import *


class User(AbstractUser):
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=(
            ('C', 'Client'),
            ('M', 'Manager'),
            ('D', 'Director'),
        ),
        default='C',
    )
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, validators=[])
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, unique=True, validators=[validate_phone])


class Client(User):
    company = models.OneToOneField('Company', null=True)
    loyalty = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    requisites = models.OneToOneField('Requisites', null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    curator = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manager',
        related_name='clients',
        null=True,
    )
```

For this purpose I have a RegistrationView:

```
class RegistrationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            new_user = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And a RegistrationSerializer:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    is_accepted = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    second_name = serializers.CharField(required=False) 
    company = CompanySerializer(required=False)
    requisites = RequisitesSerializer(required=False)  
    address = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def validate_is_accepted(self, value):
        if not value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Вы не дали согласия на обработку персональных данных.')
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.copy()
        data.pop('is_accepted')
        data['username'] = 'user' + str(User.objects.count())
        data['is_active'] = False
        return Client.objects.create_user(**data)
```

I use is_accepted field to determine is new user accepted to process his personal data. This field, obviously, isn't contained in User model. It's only for registration purposes, so I need to remove this field before creating new user. And as you see I do it in create method of RegistrationSerializer. 
However when I try to register new user it looks like is_accepted field hasn't been removed because I get the traceback below. So I checked it using logging and it's ok - is_accepted field isn't contained in validated_data which I put as argument to create_user method. It contains only model fields. So I don't understand this error. Could you please explain what is going on?

```
AttributeError at /auth/registration/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `is_accepted` on serializer `RegistrationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Client` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Client' object has no attribute 'is_accepted'.

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://95.213.203.11/auth/registration/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Python Executable: /root/ss/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path: ['.', '', '/root/ss/lib/python36.zip', '/root/ss/lib/python3.6', '/root/ss/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages']


Traceback:  

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  441.             return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  100.                 instance = getattr(instance, attr)


      During handling of the above exception ('Client' object has no attribute 'is_accepted'), another exception occurred:



File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "./auth/views.py" in post
  18.             return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  533.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  262.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  487.                 attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)

File "/root/ss/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in get_attribute
  462.             raise type(exc)(msg)
```

Comment: why not simply add a field is_accepted in user model?

Comment: @Luv33preet Yes, in this case registration works.

Comment: Why did you copy validated_data? And Can I see Client create_user function?

Comment: @origamic I copy it just because of habit - do not change function input data. Client create_user function is a built-in django.contrib.auth function, I didn't make any changes in it.Client inherits from User class which inherits from built-in AbstractUser class. Ok, I'll add models.